# What is the lifetime of a Windows icon (LoadImage) Handle?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm writing a small MFC app and loading an icon handle like this in my executable upon launch:

```
const HANDLE hIconLarge = ::LoadImage(AfxGetInstanceHandle()
   MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_EXAMPLE), IMAGE_ICON,
   ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON), ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON), 0);
```

I am retaining this same handle in another class in a DLL I created by simply assigning it like this:

```
m_hLargeWindowIcon = p_hLargeIconHandle;
```

where `m_hLargeWindowIcon` is a private class `HANDLE` variable in a singleton that I call `IconManager`. I then later occasionally use this icon handle to set the large icon for pop-up windows that my DLL creates.

It seems to be working fine, but I am concerned about the life cycle of the handle I am retaining.

Is it safe to save a handle in this fashion (i.e. the handle will remain valid until the host process of my DLL is terminated) or can I run into issues where the handle may not be valid when I access it at a later point in time? Should I be using `DuplicateHandle` or something to that nature in this case?

Comment: `DuplicateHandle` is for use with KERNEL objects. `HICON` refers to a USER object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifetime of the icon is as long as a valid handle to it (`HICON`) exists, else, it'll get cleaned up when the process exits.

Normally you would want to wrap the functionality up in a `Icon` class of some sort with appropriate copy and move semantics. Or at the very least tie it to a RAII class to manage the lifetime of the [`HICON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648072(v=vs.85).aspx).

Given the singleton nature of its use here, that may be overkill. Let the singleton clean it up [`DestroyIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648063(v=vs.85).aspx) when the program exits. One caveat here is that you really should be sure that clients of the code don't try clean it up for you. Once they have a bit copy, sure, there is little you can do to stop them, but at least be clear in the documentation how the code behaves and some reason as to why (since this seems to be a corner case w.r.t. the resource management).

Side note: I believe the correct function to duplicate an icon is [`CopyIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648058(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to duplicate the handle in any way. Your usage is fine, apart from the fact that you are using the wrong type. Instead of `HANDLE` you should use `HICON`.

When nothing more refers to that icon handle, you do need to destroy it. Call `DestroyIcon` to do so.